# Browserify and Rendr using Gulp

Tags: browserify, gulp, rendr

I am trying to browserify a Rendr application. I have tried multiple ways with no success.

Here is one version that I have tried using Gulp-browserify(Now deprecated in favor of plain browserify).

```
gulp.task('browserify-gulp', function() {
    gulp.src(['app/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(gulpbrowserify())
    .pipe(concat('mergedGulp.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
  });
```

And this errors out

```
Error: module "app/router" not found from rendr_project/node_modules/rendr/shared/app.js"
```

Here is a different approach using stock Browserify and vinyl-source-stream. This gives me the same error.

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  var bundle = browserify( './app/app.js' ).bundle();
  return bundle.pipe(source( 'mergedAssets.js' )).pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});
```

The line in .../shared/app.js that cause this behavior is

```
if (!isServer) {
  ClientRouter = require('app/router');// <---here
  Backbone.$ = window.$ || require('jquery');
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, here is the same task using Grunt and Grunt-Browserify.

```
browserify: {
    options: {
      debug: true,
      alias: [
        'node_modules/rendr-handlebars/index.js:rendr-handlebars'
      ],
      aliasMappings: [
        {
          cwd: 'app/',
          src: ['**/*.js'],
          dest: 'app/'
        }
      ],
      shim: {
        jquery: {
          path: 'assets/vendor/jquery.js',
          exports: '$'
        }
      }
    },
    app: {
      src: [ 'app/**/*.js' ],
      dest: 'public/mergedAssets.js'
    }
  }
});
```

This works great, but I would like to move everything over to gulp which seems much more intuitive.

EDIT:

I have found a work around using gulp-browserify.

```
gulp.src(['app/**/*.js'])
  .pipe(browserify({
    insertGlobals: true,
    debug: !gulp.env.production
  }).on('prebundle', function(bundler) {
    bundler.require( __dirname + '/app/router', {expose: 'app/router'} );
    bundler.require( __dirname + '/app/views/base', {expose: '../base'});
  }))
  .pipe(concat('mergedAssets.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
```

This compiles and the app seems to be working, but the file output seems to have ballooned to over 8 mb while the file compiled with grunt-browserify is steady at 1.5mb. I also see errors in the browsers console where certain modules are not being found. Another downside it gulp-browserify being blacklisted. And it seems that browserify does not have support for the 'prebundle' event.

You can also see that I have to require two files in my app. Currently there are a total of 6 files. I imagine as the app becomes complex I will have to manually require more files.

AliasMapping is indeed a much needed feature of Browserify. Hopefully someone knows a way to get this working using just Browserify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, looks like someone figured it out for me. As you can see below, its not very friendly or Gulpy. Looks like a someone needs to make a bundler specifically for Gulp because this is horrible to look at.

It spits out the same size file as grunt-browserify does. So thats a pass.

```
var rendrClientFiles = glob.sync('rendr/{client,shared}/**/*.js', { cwd : './node_modules/' });
var rendrModules = rendrClientFiles.map(function (file) {
  return file.replace('.js', '')
});

/**
 * Bundle SquidInk app
 * @param globs
 * @returns {*}
 */
var getBundler = function (globs) {

  var bundler, files;

  bundler = browserify({
    fullPaths : false,
    entries   : []
  });

  globs.forEach(function (pattern) {
    files = glob.sync(pattern, { cwd : './' });
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      // it's nesessary for some app modules (e.g. 'app/app')
      // to be exposed otherwise rendr couldn't require them
      var moduleName = file.replace(/.js$/, '');
      bundler.require('./' + file, { expose: moduleName});
    });
  });

  rendrModules.forEach(function (moduleName) {
    bundler.require(moduleName);
  });

  bundler.require('rendr-handlebars');
  bundler.require('jquery');

  return bundler;
};

gulp.task('browserify:app', function() {
  var bundler = getBundler([ 'app/**/*.js' ]),
    options = { insertGlobals : false, debug : true };

  return bundler.bundle(options)
    .pipe(plumberPlus())
    .pipe(source('mergedAssets.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
});
```

Credits:   https://github.com/dettier/rendr/blob/4f2c96b8233830430eee5841b34a9f9cd47e9a34/examples/07_gulp/gulpfile.js

Answer (score 0):

I am actually having the same issue right now. the problem is in the missing aliasMapping in gulp-browserify and node-browserify. checkout https://github.com/deepak1556/gulp-browserify/issues/46 I am trying to find a way around it using shortify but keep getting errors about missing modules from inside rendr like missing "rendr/shared/app/". hope this might get the brain storming going.

Comment: I haven't given shortify a try yet, mainly because I don't understand what it is doing. I will give it a shot next time I have free time.

Comment: This was the reason why I am still using the old version of browserify that support alias! :/